# What is the best approach to database abstraction layer for Angular?

Tags: android, angular

What is the best approach to database abstraction layer for Angular, similar to something like a Content Provider in Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many developers build an interface to define the entity data and a set of Angular services that handle the data retrieval. If you are interested in using a declarative, stream-based architectural style, then you define the RxJS streams in those services.

Here is an example:

**product.ts**

```
/* Defines the product entity */
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode?: string;
  description?: string;
  price?: number;
  categoryId?: number;
  category?: string;
  quantityInStock?: number;
  searchKey?: string[];
  supplierIds?: number[];
}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productsUrl = 'api/products';


  // All products
  products$ = this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Products', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```